# In PHP can I change all 1000, 2000, 3000 format to 1K, 2K, 3K format in this code

Tags: php

I have 0 experience in php coding, but I need to change this code to let show 1k, 2k, 3k etc..., here is is the full code:

```
if (!function_exists('get_theme_currency')) {
function get_theme_currency()
{
    $currency = get_option('theme_currency_sign');
    if (!empty($currency)) {
        return $currency;
    }
    return __('$', 'framework');
}
if (!function_exists('get_property_price')) {
function get_property_price()
{
    global $post;
    $price_digits = doubleval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price', true));
    if ($price_digits) {
        $currency            = get_theme_currency();
        $price_post_fix      = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price_postfix', true);
        $decimals            = intval(get_option('theme_decimals'));
        $decimal_point       = get_option('theme_dec_point');
        $thousands_separator = get_option('theme_thousands_sep');
        $currency_position   = get_option('theme_currency_position');
        $formatted_price     = number_format($price_digits, $decimals, $decimal_point, $thousands_separator);
        if ($currency_position == 'after') {
            return $formatted_price . $currency . ' ' . $price_post_fix;
        } else {
            return $currency . $formatted_price . ' ' . $price_post_fix;
        }
    } else {
        return __('NA', 'framework');
    }
}
if (!function_exists('property_price')) {
function property_price()
{
    echo get_property_price();
}
if (!function_exists('get_custom_price')) {
function get_custom_price($amount)
{
    $amount = doubleval($amount);
    if ($amount) {
        $currency            = get_theme_currency();
        $decimals            = intval(get_option('theme_decimals'));
        $decimal_point       = get_option('theme_dec_point');
        $thousands_separator = get_option('theme_thousands_sep');
        $currency_position   = get_option('theme_currency_position');
        $formatted_price     = number_format($amount, $decimals, $decimal_point, $thousands_separator);
        if ($currency_position == 'after') {
            return $formatted_price . $currency;
        } else {
            return $currency . $formatted_price;
        }
    } else {
        return __('NA', 'framework');
    }
}
if (!function_exists('advance_location_options')) {
function advance_location_options($taxonomy_name)
{
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy_name, array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent' => 0
    ));
    $searched_term  = '';
    if ($taxonomy_name == 'property-city') {
        if (!empty($_GET['location'])) {
            $searched_term = $_GET['location'];
        }
    }
    generate_hirarchical_options($taxonomy_name, $taxonomy_terms, $searched_term);
    if ($searched_term == 'any' || empty($searched_term)) {
        echo '<option value="any" selected="selected">' . __('Any', 'framework') . '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="any">' . __('Any', 'framework') . '</option>';
    }
}
if (!function_exists('min_prices_list')) {
function min_prices_list()
{
    $min_price_array      = array(
        1000,
        5000,
        10000,
        50000,
        100000,
        200000,
        300000,
        400000,
        500000,
        600000,
        700000,
        800000,
        900000,
        1000000,
        1500000,
        2000000,
        2500000,
        5000000
    );
    $minimum_price_values = get_option('theme_minimum_price_values');
    if (!empty($minimum_price_values)) {
        $min_prices_string_array = explode(',', $minimum_price_values);
        if (is_array($min_prices_string_array) && !empty($min_prices_string_array)) {
            $new_min_prices_array = array();
            foreach ($min_prices_string_array as $string_price) {
                $integer_price = doubleval($string_price);
                if ($integer_price > 1) {
                    $new_min_prices_array[] = $integer_price;
                }
            }
            if (!empty($new_min_prices_array)) {
                $min_price_array = $new_min_prices_array;
            }
        }
    }
    $minimum_price = '';
    if (isset($_GET['min-price'])) {
        $minimum_price = doubleval($_GET['min-price']);
    }
    if (!empty($min_price_array)) {
        foreach ($min_price_array as $price) {
            if ($minimum_price == $price) {
                echo '<option value="' . $price . '" selected="selected">' . get_custom_price($price) . '</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option value="' . $price . '">' . get_custom_price($price) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    if ($minimum_price == 'any' || empty($minimum_price)) {
        echo '<option value="any" selected="selected">' . __('Any', 'framework') . '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="any">' . __('Any', 'framework') . '</option>';
    }
}
if (!function_exists('max_prices_list')) {
function max_prices_list()
{
    $max_price_array      = array(
        5000,
        10000,
        50000,
        100000,
        200000,
        300000,
        400000,
        500000,
        600000,
        700000,
        800000,
        900000,
        1000000,
        1500000,
        2000000,
        2500000,
        5000000,
        10000000
    );
    $maximum_price_values = get_option('theme_maximum_price_values');
    if (!empty($maximum_price_values)) {
        $max_prices_string_array = explode(',', $maximum_price_values);
        if (is_array($max_prices_string_array) && !empty($max_prices_string_array)) {
            $new_max_prices_array = array();
            foreach ($max_prices_string_array as $string_price) {
                $integer_price = doubleval($string_price);
                if ($integer_price > 1) {
                    $new_max_prices_array[] = $integer_price;
                }
            }
            if (!empty($new_max_prices_array)) {
                $max_price_array = $new_max_prices_array;
            }
        }
    }
    $maximum_price = '';
    if (isset($_GET['max-price'])) {
        $maximum_price = doubleval($_GET['max-price']);
    }
    if (!empty($max_price_array)) {
        foreach ($max_price_array as $price) {
            if ($maximum_price == $price) {
                echo '<option value="' . $price . '" selected="selected">' . get_custom_price($price) . '</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option value="' . $price . '">' . get_custom_price($price) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    if ($maximum_price == 'any' || empty($maximum_price)) {
        echo '<option value="any" selected="selected">' . __('Any', 'framework') . '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="any">' . __('Any', 'framework') . '</option>';
    }
}
```

Here is the cod Andy ask me to find, I hope this is the one:

```
        if( isset($_GET['min-price']) && ($_GET['min-price'] != 'any') && isset($_GET['max-price']) && ($_GET['max-price'] != 'any') ){
        $min_price = doubleval($_GET['min-price']);
        $max_price = doubleval($_GET['max-price']);
        if( $min_price >= 0 && $max_price > $min_price ){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'REAL_HOMES_property_price',
                'value' => array( $min_price, $max_price ),
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            );
        }
    }elseif( isset($_GET['min-price']) && ($_GET['min-price'] != 'any') ){
        $min_price = doubleval($_GET['min-price']);
        if( $min_price > 0 ){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'REAL_HOMES_property_price',
                'value' => $min_price,
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '>='
            );
        }
    }elseif( isset($_GET['max-price']) && ($_GET['max-price'] != 'any') ){
        $max_price = doubleval($_GET['max-price']);
        if( $max_price > 0 ){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'REAL_HOMES_property_price',
                'value' => $max_price,
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '<='
            );
        }
    }

    if( isset($_GET['min-area']) && !empty($_GET['min-area']) && isset($_GET['max-area']) && !empty($_GET['max-area']) ){
        $min_area = intval($_GET['min-area']);
        $max_area = intval($_GET['max-area']);
        if( $min_area >= 0 && $max_area > $min_area ){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'REAL_HOMES_property_size',
                'value' => array( $min_area, $max_area ),
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            );
        }
    }elseif( isset($_GET['min-area']) && !empty($_GET['min-area']) ){
        $min_area = intval($_GET['min-area']);
        if( $min_area > 0 ){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'REAL_HOMES_property_size',
                'value' => $min_area,
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '>='
            );
        }
    }elseif( isset($_GET['max-area']) && !empty($_GET['max-area']) ){
        $max_area = intval($_GET['max-area']);
        if( $max_area > 0 ){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'REAL_HOMES_property_size',
                'value' => $max_area,
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '<='
            );
        }
    }
```

Here is another 2 more codes I found that rendering this dropdown price

```
    $('#select-min-price,#select-max-price').change(function(obj, e){
        var min_text_val = $('#select-min-price').val();
        var min_int_val = (isNaN(min_text_val))?0:parseInt(min_text_val);

        var max_text_val = $('#select-max-price').val();
        var max_int_val = (isNaN(max_text_val))?0:parseInt(max_text_val);

        if( (min_int_val >= max_int_val) && (min_int_val != 0) && (max_int_val != 0)){
            $('#select-max-price_input,#select-min-price_input').css('outline','2px solid red');
        }else{
            $('#select-max-price_input,#select-min-price_input').css('outline','none');
        }
    });


    $('#min-area,#max-area').change(function(obj, e){
        var min_text_val = $('#min-area').val();
        var min_int_val = (isNaN(min_text_val))?0:parseInt(min_text_val);

        var max_text_val = $('#max-area').val();
        var max_int_val = (isNaN(max_text_val))?0:parseInt(max_text_val);

        if( (min_int_val >= max_int_val) && (min_int_val != 0) && (max_int_val != 0)){
            $('#min-area,#max-area').css('outline','2px solid red');
        }else{
            $('#min-area,#max-area').css('outline','none');
        }
    });
```

I got this code from WordPress theme called Real Homes, in the settings I can only put 1000, I tried to make it 1K, it disappeared from the dropdown select list.

Do I have to change the whole code, or I have to replace it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like it's just the code to show what you're talking about. It's referencing a lot of other functions that probably handle the actual numbers. However saying that i would say the line $price_digits = doubleval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price', true)); probably holds some key information in it

Comment: Thank you Andy for answer, I will try it, sorry for putting only code, I just put the this code that refer to the price in page, if you want to ask me anything related to it, please do, here is the link I am talking about http://www.cwhome.me/ Thank you again

Comment: Sorry Andy, I couldn't find where to put this code you give me, I am so confused if you can help me with that, Thank you

Comment: Sorry mate, that's a line already in that code you posted. We would need to see the code that all that line links to, i think all the stuff you want to handle is inside the functions in that line

Comment: What will be the name of that line, did you make out, I will search for it, if you tell me what is that line, and thank you very much for your time checking

Comment: The line is what i copied from your code... It's right there in your question lol. You need to investigate the functions bound to that line. For example the doubleval() function and what REAL_HOMES_property_price is defined as in the other files. What you have pasted is not the entire script and you will need to dig deeper to find the values that are being output

Comment: I will do that and edit my question with this line, Thanks again

Comment: Hi Andy, I added the code to my question, I found it at the same file that called function.php, I had to open all the files in the server and make search at all files opened in my Coda2, then I found it at the same file that I got the first code, I hope that helps, and I hope you have the time to help me, Thank you

Comment: Looks like you just need to find the bit of code that is rendering those dropdown values. That's what will need changing

Comment: Hi Andy, I added 2 codes that I found thru searching by expect element thru firefox. I then search on the codes on the server. I hope this is is the code. sorry for making this too long

Comment: You need to find the actual <select></select> tags that hold the values.